# Добавление лицензионного ключа

Tags: c++, c

Мне нужно добавить в программу проверку на лицензию. У меня есть набор ключей и функция, проверяющая их валидность. Я не знаю, как лучше связать ее с `int main` и как проверять ключи (т.е. надо как-то их хранить и брать откуда-то).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, судя по всему, это у вас не банковская система, и от взлома вы не пострадаете (разве что морально), так что просто пишется функция типа

```
bool checkKey(const string& key);
```

которая потом в `main` вызывается типа

```
int main()
{

    string key;
    cout << "Enter key: ";
    cin >> key;
    if (!checkKey(key))
    {
        cout << "Wrong key!\n";
        return 1;
    }
```

Ну, а сама функция может, например, проверять наличие ключа в файле с выданными ключами, или, например, ключ должен обладать какими-то особыми свойствами - типа, какая-то контрольная сумма должна иметь определенное значение, или сумма цифр на четных и нечетных местах совпадать (или отличаться, скажем, на 13) - вобщем, что в голову взбредет, такие ключи и создавайте и проверяйте.

Только, конечно, это все легко ломаемо, но еще раз - судя по вопросу, это не серьезная задача защиты суперсофта от любых кулхацкеров :)

Comment: Да это понятно, это защита от школьников. У меня есть уже `checkKey`, мне как раз и надогде-то хранить ключ, чтоб каждый раз при запуске не спрашивать.

Comment: Сейчас делают активацию по Сети. Храните на удаленном сервере - отправляйте ключ по шифрованному каналу, чтоб не как от школьников была защита.

Comment: @GarfieldCat Я знаю, но серваки с БД все платые, так бы можно было

Comment: @PoulShipilov Чтоб безопастно хранить пароль "на компе", надо использовать API которое предоставляет операционная система. Для Windows смотри  CryptEncrypt и все что рядом. Система  "зашифрует"  пароль,  который можно расшифровать только под этой учетной записью. Для iPhone, например, шифрованое хранилище привязывается к icloud+программа или icloud+vendor.

Comment: Сложновато конечно,- можно сделать dll на C# для работы с Google Drive и работать с dll из C++

Comment: @PavelGridin А через какие библиотеки все это делается?

Comment: через гугловские, https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet